# GLB exports static object with animation keyframes

Tags: animation, export, keyframes, gltf

I have noticed a strange behavior from the GLB exporter the other day when loading a glb file to https://gltf.report/

The file had an armature with animation and few more animated objects and static ones,
the odd thing was when exporting the GLB the report showed animation keyframes on the static objects that had no keyframes or animations on them at all(!)

I am sharing few examples for you to look at https://filebin.net/vmzajtl4ys8wqpur

Answer (score 0):

After bashing my head and ticking on and off a few of the boxes on the GLB export panel, I have noticed that when **not ticking Limit to - Selected Objects** the export works as intended. This seems like a bug in the exporter.

Just wanted to share this in case someone else will encounter this issue,
I will also try to contact GLTF/Blender people.

Comment: Report it as a bug via the Help > Report a Bug menu in Blender.

Comment: Sounds like it may be a bug in the glTF exporter.  The exporter has its own issue tracking separate from Blender, try reporting one here: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues

Comment: I have, you can see the reply here https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender-addons/issues/104417